# Using LINQ - Concat duplicate columns

Tags: linq

I have a list like:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
--------+---------+---------
111     | 222     | xx
111     | 222     | yy
111     | 222     | zz
```

but I want to transfer as:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
--------+---------+---------
111     | 222     | xx, yy, zz
```

If possible, I would like in the same list without creating more list to achieve the result using LINQ. Does anyone have a idea how to do this?

Comment: Why does it have to be in the same list as apposed to a new list?

Comment: Is this Linq to Sql, Linq to Entities, Linq or Objects.  In other words are you hitting the database?  If so are you using EF or Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 1):

VB version, (use Tuple as I don't know your object definition):

> ```
>     Dim list = New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, String))
>
>     list.Add(Tuple.Create(111, 222, "xx"))
>     list.Add(Tuple.Create(111, 222, "yy"))
>     list.Add(Tuple.Create(111, 222, "zz"))
>
>     Dim result = list.GroupBy(Function(n) Tuple.Create(n.Item1, n.Item2)) _
>         .Select(Function(m) Tuple.Create(m.Key.Item1, m.Key.Item2, m.Select(Function(t) t.Item3).Aggregate(Function(x, y) x & "," & y)))
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are looking for doing it in the same list... But here is the LINQ query;

```
List<Column> list = new List<Column>();

var newList = list.GroupBy(x => new { A = x.ColumnA, B = x.ColumnB })
            .Select(y => new Column
            {
                ColumnA = y.Key.A,
                ColumnB = y.Key.B,
                ColumnC = y.ToList().Select(el => el.ColumnC).Aggregate((y1, y2) => y1 + "," + y2)
            });



class Column
{
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
    public string ColumnB { get; set; }
    public string ColumnC { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Columns> list = new List<Columns>() {new Columns(){Column1="111",Column2="222",Column3="xx"},
        new Columns(){Column1="111",Column2="222",Column3="yy"},
        new Columns(){Column1="111",Column2="222",Column3="zz"}
        };
        var result=list.GroupBy(c=>new { c.Column1, c.Column2 })
            .Select(g=>new Columns(){Column1=g.Key.Column1,Column2=g.Key.Column2,Column3=string.Join(",",g.Select(s=>s.Column3))});
    }
}

public class Columns
{
    public string Column1;
    public string Column2;
    public string Column3;
}
```